# what is the next step?

Tags: java, python, qooxdoo

When I type "python" it displays:

```
ActivePython 2.6.5.14 (ActiveState Software Inc.)
based on Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jul 4 2010, 21:05:58)
[MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This is what I get at the command line:

```
>>> python create-application.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python create-application.py
       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should I do to work in Qooxdoo.

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow?  Please include the title or a link to the tutorial.

Comment: http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/requirements this is the one that is confusing everytime. Nothing is happening for me alone even i try tis for 2 days. Please fix this

Comment: You should try and learn a bit more about the command line, file and folder manipulation, and Python if you want to follow this sort of tutorial. Running a script in the interpreter instead of the command line is a bit of a revealing mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you are confusing between the Python [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and the [command line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). You should be calling  `python create-application.py` from the command line ("cmd" in Windows) and not from the REPL (which is what you get when you type `python` on the command line).

I suggest reading up on the basics before venturing further. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the command `python create-application.py` from the command line, not from within the interpreter.

You have already started the Python interpreter, probably by typing `python` at the command line. (You can tell, because the `>>>` prompt is a Python standard.) This is a program that accepts *Python code* -- but `python create-application.py` isn't Python code, it's a system command. You run those from the command line.

I assume you're not planning to use Python to program (just to run this script) but if you are, I recommend [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) for a tutorial.