# Getting started with Qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, qooxdoo

i downloaded Qooxdoo, then ActivePython and installed it as in this tutorial http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/helloworld. When I follow the instructions I get the following results:

1. `C:\qooxdoo-1.1-sdk\tool\bin\create-application.py
   --name=custom --out=C:` - this command opens a "create-application" wordfile.
2. `cd C:\custom`
3. inside `c:\custom` I typed `generate.py source-all` but I got the following error

> 'generate.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What's gone wrong? I'm stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the next step ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493377/what-is-the-next-step)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate - that's struggling with Python in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute .pys from the command line on Windows like that you'll need to add `.py` to your PATHEXT environment variable.

You might also need to make sure that ActivePython's bin directory is in your path. If it is, you can then equivalently run `python generate.py`.